# Extract file(s) to hard-drive from `archive-mode`

Tags: elisp, archive-mode

I'm looking for a means to extract individual *and* marked files from archives (e.g., *.zip; *.gz, etc.) to the hard-drive (without opening them in a buffer) using `archive-mode`.  A suggested modification of that major-mode (that would permit this new feature) will be greatly appreciated.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Archives.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a sketch of an implementation.

Archive mode stores maps from archive types to commands used to extract data in variables `archive-TYPE-extract`; we can find the right variable using `(archive-name "extract")`.

All commands are tailored for extracting to standard out; luckily we can still use them if we redirect `stdout` to a file of our choice.

```
(defun archive-extract-to-file (archive-name item-name command dir)
  "Extract ITEM-NAME from ARCHIVE-NAME using COMMAND. Save to
DIR."
  (unwind-protect
      ;; remove the leading / from the file name to force
      ;; expand-file-name to interpret its path as relative to dir
      (let* ((file-name (if (string-match "\\`/" item-name)
                            (substring item-name 1)
                          item-name))
             (output-file (expand-file-name file-name dir))
             (output-dir (file-name-directory output-file)))
        ;; create the output directory (and its parents) if it does
        ;; not exist yet
        (unless (file-directory-p output-dir)
          (make-directory output-dir t))
        ;; execute COMMAND, redirecting output to output-file
        (apply #'call-process
               (car command)            ;program
               nil                      ;infile
               `(:file ,output-file)    ;destination
               nil                      ;display
               (append (cdr command) (list archive-name item-name))))
    ;; FIXME: add unwind forms
    nil))
```

I modified `archive-extract-by-file` to get this.

```
(defun archive-extract-marked-to-file (output-dir)
  "Extract marked archive items to OUTPUT-DIR."
  (interactive "sOutput directory: ")
  (let ((command (symbol-value (archive-name "extract")))
        (archive (buffer-file-name))
        (items (archive-get-marked ?* t))) ; get marked items; t means
                                           ; get item under point if
                                           ; nothing is marked
    (mapc
     (lambda (item)
       (archive-extract-to-file archive
                                (aref item 0) ; get the name from the descriptor
                                command output-dir))
     items)))
```

Here I use `mapc` to loop over all marked files and extract them.

Now we just need to add a key binding:

```
(require 'arc-mode)
(define-key archive-mode-map "F" #'archive-extract-marked-to-file)
```

I tested this on a dummy `.zip` file containing a subdirectory, but your mileage may vary.

Note that `archive-mode` supports `Arc`, `Lzh`, `Zip`, `Zoo`, `Rar`, and `7z`. It does **not** support `.tgz`, `.tbz`, `.tar.gz` and friends, which are opened using `tar-mode` and `uncompress.el`.

Comment: @lawlist: Please see the updated answer; now it should be able to extract files contained in subdirectories. Note that it re-creates the directory structure: `foo/bar.txt` in an archive gets extracted to `output-dir/foo/bar.txt`, not to `output-dir/bar.txt`. The latter is possible, of course, but would require some more code.

Comment: That's really nice. Once you feel confident with it, would you consider adding it to archive-mode itself?

Comment: @Malabarba: Yes, I would. I'm waiting for a reply from `copyright-clerk@fsf.org` (I got this e-mail from [Lars Ingebrigtsen](http://lars.ingebrigtsen.no/2014/11/13/welcome-new-emacs-developers/)) right now; in the meantime I'll clean this up and put it on GitHub.

Comment: This new feature is awesome!  Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated!  This would indeed be a wonderful addition to archive-mode.  As you noted, the ability to target a specific output directory without necessarily re-creating the zip-archive directory structure (in the output directory) would be handy.  As is, it is certainly worthy of a checkmark+ for the correct answer  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code! One thing though: it'd be better to `(interactive "G...")` this way it will suggest the current directory, plus it'll autocomplete and interact with Ido mode etc.

Comment: I made a small improvement on this code: https://gist.github.com/cpbotha/05e07dee7fd8243ba73339be186c0b88 - 1. it will now auto-suggest your other dired pane's directory as output and 2. it will by default NOT extract relative paths, unless you do `C-u` prefix.