# Can't open zip files in emacs

Tags: archive-mode

When I try to open a zip file in emacs I just see the binary file instead of a listing of the files.

I get the following backgrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range 36585 36589)
  archive-zip-summarize()
  archive-summarize(nil)
  archive-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(archive-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer cmyk.zip> "~/Downloads/cmyk.zip" nil nil "~/Downloads/cmyk.zip" (9179932 64513))
  find-file-noselect("/home/thayne/Downloads/cmyk.zip" nil nil nil)
  find-file("/home/thayne/Downloads/cmyk.zip")
```

The numbers in args-out-of-range change depending on the zip file.

I have googled around and can't find anything that works. This happens for EVERY zip file.

**EDIT**

I am using emacs 24.3.1, I can get a listing when I use `emacs -q`, so I guess it is something in my configuration.

I am using Prelude with a number of plugins installed, I'm not sure how to narrow down on what plugin and/or configuration is causing the problem though.

Comment: Constantine wrote some code to extract the contents of zip archives to the hard drive once they have been displayed in `archive-mode`, perhaps something like that would be what you are looking for?:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3843/2287  I know you are interested in `archive-mode`, however, `dired-mode` is more sophisticated in some respects and it can be configured to unzip `*.zip` files (but not display their contents beforehand, absent a modification to the code).

Comment: `archive-mode` *lists the **contents** of the zip archive*, instead of uncompressing it.  It can extract a file from the zip archive to a buffer (but not extract a file from the zip archive to the hard drive without using code similar to what Constantine wrote).

Comment: What version of Emacs do you have? Does this happen if you run `emacs -q`? if you run `emacs -Q`?

Comment: sorry I wasn't more clear in the original post. I meant that it wasn't listing the contents, just showing a bunch of gibberish on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had the following line in my configuration:

```
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
```

Deleting this line fixed it. I originally put this in because a website recommended doing this to make utf-8 the default coding system, however I later found a different way to do it, and the documentation for coding-system-for-read actually says not to set it globally. I feel like an idiot.